# Unknown column 'categories1_.category' in 'field list'

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the following model.

Employee.Java

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "category")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "myobject_categories", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "myobject_id"))
    private Set<Category> categories;
}
```

Category is an Enum as follows.

```
public enum Category {
CATEGORY(1), CATEGORY2(2);

private final Integer id;
Category(Integer id) { this.id=id; }
public Integer getId() { return id; }
}
```

My Repository is as follows,

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    @Query("from org.arunm.Employee c WHERE :category MEMBER OF c.categories")
    List<Employee> findAll(@Param("category") Set<Category> categories);
}
```

The following code to retrieve the list of employees is not working.

```
Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<Category>();
categories.add(Category.CATEGORY);
List<Employee> list = customerRepository.findAll(categories);
customer.setCategories(categories);
customerRepository.findAll(categories);
```

In the logs I am seeing the query generated as

```
select employee0_.id as id1_1_, employee0_.first_name as first_na2_1_, employee0_.last_name as last_nam3_1_ from employee employee0_ where ? in 
(select categories1_.category from myobject_categories categories1_ where employee0_.id=categories1_.myobject_id)
```

Following is the error that I am getting,

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'categories1_.category' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

My question is what is it in my mapping that is forcing hibernate to think that there is a column called **category** in **myobject_categories** table.

Comment: I don't know it for sure, but I think a collection is not allowed on the left hand side. But the category field relates to the generated table which should have this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told hibernate to use `myobject_categories` as the mapping table. Such a mapping table needs to references: one back to the mapped entity (`Employee` in this case) and on to the entity that makes up the collection. Probably based on the enum name Hibernate assumed the name `category` for that field.

You might want to consider a [different way of mapping Collections of enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416208/jpa-map-collection-of-enums).