# JPA: How to fetch eagerly an embedded element collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Consider the following model

```
@Entity
// JPA and JAXB annotations here
public class Employee implements Serializable {
     // other fields, annotations, stuffs
     ...
     @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        targetClass = Address.class)
     @CollectionTable(name = "employee_address",
        schema = "hris",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id",
                nullable = false,
                referencedColumnName = "employee_id",
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT)))
     protected Set<Address> addresses;
     // setters, getters
     ...
 }

 @Embeddable
 // JAXB annotations here
 public class Address implements Serializable {
      // fields, setters, getters
 }
```

The `Address` class is annotated with `@Embeddable` annotation, and the `Employee` class has an embedded element collection of `addresses`. The element collection's `fetch` is set to `FetchType.LAZY`. Now, I would like to create a `@NamedQuery` that would retrieve all employees with addresses eagerly initialized. Knowing that `JOIN FETCH` [will only work with entity collections](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins) annotated with `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` based on JPA 2.1, how would I create a valid `JPQL` query that would allow me to eagerly retrieve embedded element collections?

Comment: How did you conclude that `join fetch` works only with entities? Did you give it a try?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic: Based on the documentation, 

"The association referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause must be an association that belongs to an entity that is returned as a result of the query. It is not permitted to specify an identification variable for the entities referenced by the right side of the FETCH JOIN clause, and hence references to the implicitly fetched entities cannot appear elsewhere in the query."

Comment: The collection-valued path must resolve to an association field

Comment: Ok, did you try it? :)

Comment: @DraganBozanovic: It may work depending on the provider, but the query is not a valid JPQL statement anymore.

Comment: _"The collection-valued path must resolve to an association field._" Why do you think that embedded collection is not considered an association field? Anyway, `[left] join fetch` is the only thing that exists in JPQL for that purpose, if that answers your question.

Comment: Have you tried using fetch profiles?

Answer (score 15):

In the JPA 2.1 specification (JSR 338) I cannot find any hint that fetch joins only work on entity relationships (but not embeddables). JSR 338, section 4.4.5.3 even states:

> A `FETCH JOIN` enables the fetching of an association **or element collection** as a side effect of the execution of a query.

As another hint the following minimal example (essentially resembling yours) executed with Hibernate 4.3.11 as JPA provider results in a single query:

Address embeddable:

```
@Embeddable public class Address { private String city; }
```

Employee entity:

```
@Entity public class Employee {

    @Id private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "address", 
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="employee_id"))
    private Set<Address> addresses;

}
```

JPQL Query:

```
em.createQuery("select e from Employee e join fetch e.addresses").getResultList();
```

Resulting SQL query:

```
select
    employee0_.id as id1_1_,
    addresses1_.employee_id as employee1_1_0__,
    addresses1_.city as city2_5_0__ 
from
    Employee employee0_ 
inner join
    address addresses1_ on employee0_.id=addresses1_.employee_id
```

So the above JPQL query seems to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6):

By the way, more effective way might be **not** to use join, but subselect

```
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@BatchSize(size=500)
```

it makes two selects, instead of one, but doesn't produce so much ambiguity.