# Hibernate: persistence optimization of lengthy ArrayLists

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I've come across multiple bottlenecks in my database usage. I'm using PostgreSQL accessed with Hibernate ORM and written in Java 8.

Here's a sample of the class that needs optimization :

```
public class RightEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ElementCollection
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private List<Long> readableEntity = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

RightEntity is an object which allows the access of a list of Ids (List of Long). The problem is whenever I load this entity, the list readableEntity, which contains hundreds of elements, can take a few seconds to load at the same time. This is a huge bottleneck because it is used in almost every API and managers of my server.

My question is : how can I optimize this code to make it run smoother ?

LazyCollectionOption.FALSE is similar to FetchType.Eager
I've tried to load it lazily, it runs a lot faster, but I end up with a LazyCollection whenever I try to load the list, so I'm exploring alternatives or a fix.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is a `JOIN FETCH` mechanism for accessing a lazy collection properly. You can use it in your JPQL query to populate a lazy collection.

Take a look at [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/) explanation from a Hibernate developer. You can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773079/jpa-how-to-fetch-eagerly-an-embedded-element-collection) SO question for alternative using batches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! If I understand correctly, you'll need to create a specific request that join your two tables. Should I use this strategy in the getter of my List (written differently so that it only returns the list) or should I use it in the first request for the entity ?