# Hibernate: Is retrieving @OneToMany association quicker than retrieving an @ElementCollection list?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, optimization, persistence

I'm trying to optimize an old codebase. Currently we use an `@ElementCollection` ArrayList to store hundreds of ids (Long).

```
 public class RightEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ElementCollection
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private List<Long> entityList = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

The problem is, it can take a few seconds to retrieve the `entityList` from the database.

I've read that an `@ElementCollection` [is hard to optimize correctly](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-elementcollection/) and [is not suited for frequent modifications](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-unidirectional-collections-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). Given these, I argued that the `@OneToMany` association is a no brainer for my case, but it's not because the real bottleneck is in the list retrieving.

So, is an `@OneToMany` association quicker to retrieve than `@ElementCollection` ?

**Note** : [Assuming we've properly optimized the `@OneToMany` association](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

**Note 2**: I know I'm eagerly fetching the list. [I still can't wrap my head around the way you're supposed to fetch it correctly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616661/hibernate-persistence-optimization-of-lengthy-arraylists)

**Edit**: [I've calculated the time required for each request to get done with an `@ElementCollection` list](https://pastebin.com/prwL6cAE). What I don't get is why some requests with as few as 3 elements returned (see Id: 189) have more time (a lot more) than some other than return a hundred elements. Is it because the database is not ordered ? Although it doesn't seem to be the case with a SQL request on PgAdmin.

Comment: Annotation `@OneToMany` describes the relationship between entities, while  `@ElementColection` allows you to store an array of data. I think it's better to store your collection in the sql array. [This article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) will help you

Comment: Thanks. However I'm having trouble making it working, the so-called hibernate classes are not available in my hibernate version (4.2.5). Would that be more optimized (e.g. quicker) to retrieve, though ?

Comment: I'll test it later