# Spring Data : How to store enum list in mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, enums, spring-data

In the following code I have a field `shopType` which is actually a `enum` , In my scenario one shop has multiple type for example shop ABC have type grocery as well as pharmacy , so I want to store a list of `enum` in my database in separate table in which two column present one is `shop_id` and other is `shop_type` so that one shop can have multiple types How can i do this ?

here is my code

**ShopDetail.java**

```
@Entity
public class ShopDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private Double latitude;

    private Double longitude;

    private float  rating;

    private Time openingTime;

    private Time closingTime;



    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
     private Collection<ShopType> shopType;


    @Column(columnDefinition=" bit(1)default 1")
    private boolean shopEnabled = true;

    //getters and setters
    }
```

**ShopType**

```
public enum ShopType {

    GROCERY,
    PHARAMACY
}
```

Comment: You could create new entity (new class) containing the ShopType and the reference to ShopDetail and map it with @OneToMany from ShopDetail.

Comment: @Michal no Its done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
@ElementCollection(targetElement = ShopType.class)
@JoinTable(name = "tblShopTypes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
@Column(name = "shopType", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Collection<ShopType> shopTypes;
```

ref: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416208/jpa-map-collection-of-enums)